# When using fopen(arg[1],"r") and fgets(), the output save as string or array?

Tags: c, fopen, fgets

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i = 0;
  char in[100], mychar[100];
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  fgets(mychar, 100, file);
  while (in[i]) {
    mychar[i] = in[i];
    putchar(toupper(mychar[i]));

    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I have another file named file.c and I write 'abcd' inside it.
This program will read a file's content and change them to capital letters. I don't know why when I typed

```
./a.out file.c
```

Nothing come out. What is wrong? I think maybe When using fopen(arg[1],"r") and fgets will make mychar as a string not array? Please have a look.Thanks.

Comment: a) you haven't done error checking on your `fopen()` call... shame on you! b) you're reading data into `mychar` and then you overwrite it based on the **uninitialized** `in` array. c) you also didn't do any error checking on your call to `fgets()`. If you make a habit of not doing error checking, one can only conclude that you don't mind having errors... no?

Comment: read the manpage for [`fgets`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets) and techincally a string in C _is_ an array of characters.

Comment: learn to use your debugger

Comment: @AlexejMagura null terminated array of chars to be precise ;)

Comment: Note: `toupper()` works with `int` values in the `unsigned char` range.  Suggest `putchar(toupper( (unsigned char) mychar[i]));`.

Comment: Note: `char *fgets(char * restrict s, int n, FILE * restrict stream);` saves data to a `char` array: the array pointed by `s`.  It also appends to its destination a '\0', thus `s` is also a C string.

Comment: Your terminology is strange; `mychar` is an array, and it might contain a string. A string is a null-terminated series of characters that exists inside an array.  The `fgets` function ensured that the array will contain a string afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

You read the contents of the file into `mychar`, but test for the uninitialized `in` char array. To fix this you can just switch the arrays

```
while (mychar[i]) {
    in[i] = mychar[i];
    putchar(toupper(in[i]));
    i++;
}
```

But you can also skip the copying and print the contents of `mychar` directly

```
while (mychar[i]) {
    putchar(toupper(mychar[i]));
    i++;
}
```

Comment: It works,thanks.I understand <br>    in[i] = mychar[i]; is redundant, but why it doesn't work? it is logic also.

Comment: It does work, when you `putchar(in[i])`. But you can do `putchar(mychar[i])` instead, and then you don't need the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(in,sizeof(in),file);
while (in[i]){
    mychar[i]=toupper(in[i]);
    putchar (mychar[i]);
```